# Bad Encoding when receiving response from HttpClient in UWP

Tags: c#, xml, rest, encoding, uwp

I am making uwp(Universal Windows Platform) application and want to deserialize this xml: http://radioa24.info/ramowka.php to object, but I got instead for scpecial characters as ł, ó some strange letters and special ones like: \n and \r:
    "Ä…"=>"ą"
    "Ä‡"=>"ć"
    "Ä™"=>"ę"
For example instead of `Poniedziałek` i got `PoniedziaÅ\u0082ek`

My code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).AsTask();
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I was trying to make some Encoding convertions but nothing worked out.
How to solve it because later I want to got my object?

```
var reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sources.Schedule));
using (var tr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultString)))
{
   Schedule = (Sources.Schedule)reader.Deserialize(res);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the response of 
http://radioa24.info/ramowka.php

is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. My code works fine in .NET Core. I recommend trying your snippet of code in .NET Core. I bet it will work. I think this is a problem in UWP.

Comment: This is driving me nuts!!! I am able to consume most REST apis in UWP, but this one REST API doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Are you by any chance referencing a .NET Standard DLL in your UWP project, and this is the project that is making the call? This is my scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Please can you try the code below, reading data as bytes solves your issue.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    Uri url = new Uri("http://radioa24.info/ramowka.php");
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseAsync = client.SendRequestAsync(httpRequest).AsTask();
    responseAsync.Wait();
    responseAsync.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    Task<IBuffer> asyncBuffer = responseAsync.Result.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync().AsTask();
    asyncBuffer.Wait();
    byte[] resultByteArray = asyncBuffer.Result.ToArray();
    string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultByteArray, 0, resultByteArray.Length);

    responseAsync.Result.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have tested both methods and saw the bad and correct chars. For this method responseString is pretty fine. Hope that works in your app too. @Levvy

Comment: You are a life saver brother!

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet notes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11018883/4620101) this should be fixed on the server. If you check the server sends back the following `Content-Type` header:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

It should tell you the encoding (`Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`), that's why it should be a server fix.

But if you are sure that this is UTF-8 (it is, because the response xml contains `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`), you can do this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetBufferAsync(uri);
var bytes = response.ToArray();
var properEncodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: I will ask friend who have this script to fix that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example that works fine with Polish words.

Method to get xml from page:

```
    public async Task<string> GetXMl(string uri)
    {
        string result = null;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Method to deserialize xml:

```
    public void DeserializeXml(string xml)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ramowka));
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var ramowka = (ramowka)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

Example how to use methods, for example in button click event:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string xml = await GetXMl("http://radioa24.info/ramowka.php");
        DeserializeXml(xml);
    }
```

Also here you are converted by Visual Studio xml to C# classes
http://pastebin.com/aJ4B1aCF

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually have almost same C# classes